# Finding apps Document directory in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, macos, osx-lion

I am using apps doc directory to save the database,i could not find where my doc dir is can anybody help me,i am using mac osx lion.Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want the actual simulator directory, or find the directory programmatically when running the app itself?

Comment: hello 5StringRyan,thanks for your response i want the actual simulator directory.

Answer (score 7):

Do you want find iOS sandbox document directory?

Try this code

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: hello virushuo,thanks for your answer actually i want to know the path where my app bundle is in maco os x lion.

Answer (score 3):

in Mac osx document directory is located in following path.

```
/Users/[username]/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/[app-id]/Documents
```